# IsGenericType & IsValueType missing from .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, coreclr

I have this code in .Net 4.6.2 and now trying to convert into .Net core however I am getting error

> Error CS1061  'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsGenericType'
>   and no extension method 'IsGenericType' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static TDest ConvertStringTo<TDest>(this string src)
    {
        if (src == null)
        {
            return default(TDest);
        }           

        return ChangeType<TDest>(src);
    }

    private static T ChangeType<T>(string value)
    {
        var t = typeof(T);

        // getting error here at t.IsGenericType
        if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
        }

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
    }
}
```

What is equivalent in .Net Core?

**Update1**

Surprisingly when I debug the code I see variable `t` has `IsGenericType`  property however I cannot use `IsGenericType` in the code. Not sure why or which namespace I need to add. I have added `using System` and `using System.Runtime` both namespaces

[image]

Comment: "when I debug the code I see variable t has IsGenericType property however I cannot use IsGenericType in the code."
 In the most cases this happens when you working with more base class in your code, so you don't see all type members. While, debugger works with reflection and could show you all type members.

Comment: yes, but when the property is `public` in base class then it should be visible in derived class

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, They are moved in .Net Core to a new `TypeInfo` class. The way to get this working is by using `GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType` & `GetTypeInfo().IsValueType` .

```
using System.Reflection;

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static TDest ConvertStringTo<TDest>(this string src)
    {
        if (src == null)
        {
            return default(TDest);
        }           

        return ChangeType<TDest>(src);
    }

    private static T ChangeType<T>(string value)
    {
        var t = typeof(T);

        // changed t.IsGenericType to t.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType
        if (t.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
        }

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
    }
}
```

Comment: @svick Is `GetTypeInfo()` extension method in some other namespace? intelisense cannot find it

Comment: Not sure why are you asking me, but yes, it's in `System.Reflection`.